# Ssl certificate file permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions

I have an Apache server that serves a web application through https with a certificate. I also have a Node.js back-end/API which handles all the applications requests.

The traffic from Apache to the client is secure, but at the moment the traffic from the client to my back-end is not. I'd like to change this by also using https for my Node.js API, using the same certificate as suggested in: [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/should-one-use-separate-ssl-certificates-for-front-end-and-back-end).

To do this I made a group `certs` and edited the `nodeapi.service` file in sytemd so that it belongs to that group. I also added the user running the node.js service to that group:

```
groups nodeuser
nodeuser : nodeuser sudo certs
```

Then I changed the permissions of the files so that the group can access them:

```
-rw-rwx--- 1 600 certs 1931 Nov 20 15:13 certificate.crt
-rw-rwx--- 1 600 certs 1704 Nov 20 15:12 certificate.key
```

I hoped this would work but node crashes:

`Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './cert/certificate.key'`

What could I have missed?

Comment: try to 'login' as the user you want the service to run under. than see if you can access the file  (or propably why you can not). I suspect permissions on directory.

Comment: the permissions on the folder are: 
`drw-r----- 2 root     certs    4096 Nov 20 15:14 cert`

Comment: Folders are executed ... in order for the group to be able to traverse the directory, the permissions need to be at least `550`  ... the execute bits active for the owner and the group... like this: `dr-xr-x---`

Comment: what @RubberStamp says. to troverse (see what is inside) you need the x permission on the directory.

Comment: It seems like the two services are on the same host. Why would you need to use TLS on a connection on the loopback adapter? This doesn’t add much security. Also, having the node user being able to sudo (presumably without a password) will be to the amusement of someone pwning your node application.

Comment: They are on the same host, but the website will get executed on the client's system, so getting the html and Javascript to them is secure, but not the calls the site makes to the API. 

The user does have a password, but i'll probably remove the sudo rights as you suggested.

Comment: Why not use Apache to reverse proxy the API requests? That is standard practice for this sort of thing. That way, you only need one configuration for TLS.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I will look into this, thx.

Answer (score 1):

The [comment by RubberStamp](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174428/ssl-certificate-file-permissions?noredirect=1#comment334949_174428) is the answer. The group `certs` had no execute permission on the folder so it could not look inside. Setting the permission of the folder to at least `550` worked.